# Watermarking in Assets

Tags: assets

I've been asked by a client if they can add a watermark credit to their images. The watermarks would need to be set on a per-image basis - there would potentially be hundreds of different image sources so we can't apply a standard watermark to them as is done by the standard EE Watermarking system. The watermark needs to be written into the image (using GD I imagine) rather than overlaid in a separate element. As, for example, the BBC does with stock images or those from other news agencies.

We're using Assets to manage the images. Does anyone have any solution for this already?

If not, my first idea of a solution is to write an extension based around the assets_file_meta_save hook - so that any text put into the 'Credit' field would be added into the image. Of course it couldn't be removed afterwards, the file would have to be re-uploaded. So that's quite tricky and pretty hacky.

Comment: Have you checked to see if EE's built-in watermarking (setup in each directory's File Upload Preferences) runs when uploading via Assets?

Comment: That adds the same watermark to all images. I edited the question to clarify what I meant by 'a per-image basis'.